# How do I add another field to facet for conditional filtering

Tags: search

I currently have a facet block that lists all sizes available for a certain category. The sizes come from a taxonomy vocabulary.

I want the sizes facet block to only show the sizes that have stocks > 1. The stocks field is a text field in the shoe content type.

Just a sidenote if it's helpful, both the stocks and sizes are indexed through apache solr and are displayed as facets through search API.

I have tried field aggregation and dependencies but neither satisfy my requirements. Any directions towards the right way would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.